# Android - How to call sounds from imageViews correctly with a method?

Tags: java, android, methods

I just try to play some sounds in android studio by clicking on pictures (imageViews).

I gave each picture a tag in the xml file:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:tag="internet"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rouven" />
```

In the main Activity i have this code but it keeps crashing:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void playPhrase(View view) {
        Button buttonPressed = (Button) view;
        Log.i("Button pressed", buttonPressed.getTag().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
                getResources().getIdentifier(buttonPressed.getTag().toString(), 
                "raw", getPackageName()));
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Can't i call this method like that? How to solve that? Im a beginner :-)

Thanks for your help
Carlo

Comment: Regarding, *"In the main Activity i have this code but it keeps crashing..."* -- crashing *how*? Do you see any error messages? Have you reviewed information that you may find in the LogCat?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Could not execute method for android:onClick --> must be this, maybe I can not cast an image to a button?

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 1):

1   put a music  file to the /res/raw , such as in.wav, in.mp3 media file (here name it as in)

2   change the code to:

```
 public void playPhrase(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                R.raw.in);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you shirley. Meanwhile i found the mistake. I just called my imageview button instead of imageview.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote the answer :)